# ApiController: missing location in response

Tags: c#, .net, http, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-apicontroller

In my API project when resource was created, there is running this code

```
public class MyCtrl : ApiController
{
    ...
    if (isSuccess)
    {
        result.Id = newResource.Id;
        var locationUrl =  Request.RequestUri + "/" + id;

        return Created(locationUrl, result);
    }
}
```

But in response I see only id, how can force WebAPI to also return locationId?

```
{
    "id": "YHEMPZIF2VHHP6X7"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first parameter of `Created` method is passed to the client side in the response headers. More precisely in the *Location* header. So in order to access it you don't have to modify the result object.

[image]

As to accessing headers on the client side. For example in ASP.NET MVC you can do it via  `Request.Headers` and in Angular via [`headers`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) property of a response object.

Answer (score 2):

like

```
if (isSuccess)
{
    var locationUrl =  Request.RequestUri + "/" + id;
    var result = new { Id:newResource.Id, locationUrl: locationUrl   }
    return Created(locationUrl, result);
}
```

Comment: Ok, I can extend result object. But is there any opportunity to use locationUrl from first param?

Comment: Sorry not sure I understand what you mean.